# Toolbar missing when running ASP.NET core from Visual Studio Code

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-code

Environment: Ubuntu 16.04, .NET Core 1.10 (1.0.0-preview2-1-003177), Visual Studio Code 1.8.1

I just generated a new ASP.NET Core app. When I run the app from a terminal window, the start up web page gets displayed as expected.

```
$ cd MyApp
$ dotnet run
```

However, the web page is slightly different when I load MyApp folder from VSC and press F5 to debug it. Specifically, the default top toolbar is missing. Toolbar items such as Home, About, Contact, etc. line up in a single column.

I have compared the generated html between the two. When run from the command line, the stylesheet links are:

```
href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"
href="/css/site.min.css"
```

When run from VCS, the links are:

```
href="/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"
href="/css/site.css"
```

On examining local file structure, I see  file `css/site.css` is present under folder `wwwroot`. However, I don't see any `lib` folder at all.

More information. Turns out `_Layout.cshtml` adds links based on environment names. When the names are Staging and Production, the generated bootstrap link is for ajax.aspnetcdn.com. For "Development," the link is "/lib/xxx."

Wondering how I force VCS to automatically populate `bootstrap.css` into `lib` directory.

Comment: Do you have a local copy of bootstrap.css? If so, what directory contains it?

Comment: Do you need to run `gulp`, `grunt`, or `npm` to install and build the client-side dependencies? I.e. do you have a gulpfile.js or package.json?

Comment: What tool did you use to generate your ASP.NET Core app?

Comment: Thank you for your help Shaun. The project was generated by running "dotnet new -t web." The code is completely untampered. Take a look at what I had to do to solve it. Guess I could have reproduced it without using VCS had I set ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT to Development.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem solved. When the website is generated, a file, `bower.json,` is created. This file has information about the bootstrap package. However, for some reason, this package is not automatically downloaded. You need to do the following:

1. From VSC, install the bower plugin by running "ext install bower."
2. Press F1 and type Bower. Next type, "Bower Update."

This is it. The plugin will download the bootstrap package and populate it in `wwwroot/lib` directory. Now, the website would work as expected from within VSC.

Hope the next version of VSC will have bower integrated.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like when your app runs from VS Code, it is not serving the CSS files.

To troubleshoot further, looking at the `launch.json`, `project.json`, and `Startup.cs` files is necessary. My guess is that your `launch.json` is setup to run under a slightly different configuration than your `dotnet run` command is from the terminal. That is resulting in...

1. not serving static files at all, or
2. not including CSS files in the app's build output.

From your question update, the problem is that your `launch.json` is running under in the Development environment and your terminal is running under the Staging or Production environment. The former serves bootstrap locally; the latter serves it from a content delivery network.

When running in the "Development" environment, you need to install bootstrap locally and ensure it's in the /lib directory at runtime. That means [installing the client-side packages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/yeoman#client-side-packages). How to do that depends on the ASP.NET Core application template your using. For instance, if you generated your app with Yeoman, then you need to restore with Bower. Check for a gulpfile.js, a bower.json file, or a package.json that downloads, installs, and builds client-side dependencies, which likely include bootstrap.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have updated my original post with more information. Would appreciate any thought that you may have to fix this problem. I am actually surprised no one else has seen this problem.

Comment: I have updated my post further. The link was generated based on environment name. Just need help in figuring out how to download bootstrap through VCS (and keep it updated).

Comment: Yes. You have two options. Option A is to serve bootstrap.css locally during development, option B is to serve it from the content delivery network (CDN) during development. Option A means making sure that 1. you have bootstrap.css locally, and that 2. you serve it from /lib at runtime (which might involve edits to your project.json). Option B means changing your `_Layout.cshtml` to serve from the CDN in all environmental configurations.